# Can I share one event across multiple calendars?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm working on a scheduling web app. I'm trying to integrate Google Calendar now.

My app will create a lot of events. In order to avoid muddying up any personal calendars, my plan is first programatically create a new calendar for any client that wants to integrate with Google Calendar.

Each new event can be seen by a handful of people. It differs from event to event. I could create a copy of the event for each user that opts-in to GCal, but it might be nicer if I could create only one copy, share it among all the users, and have it only show on their new app-specific calendar.

Is that possible?

Comment: If you don't want to add each event you create to others personal calendar, then create a service account, have a calendar to that account. Create events to that calendar and share it with the users under that account.

Comment: If you want to add events to users calendars, then you should first have access to their calendars. If they are going to be part of invitees list, then while creating event, if you add their email address in the guests lists, then event will be automatically created to their calendars.

Comment: I think I might make the event creator the owner and put the event on their calendar, and then make everyone else an 'attendee'. This will be a bit more work because I don't think I can prevent the owner from editing the event in google calendar which means I have to push the edits back to my app again, but... I think this workable.